# Scheduling spark job via marathon

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I want to schedule spark job to run on daily basis via marathon. I am using mesos as cluster manager.

How to schedule a job to run only once a day via marathon. Right now the job keeps on running again and again once it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to schedule periodic job on Marathon. You need to use another framework

- [Metronome](https://github.com/dcos/metronome)
- [Chronos](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/)
- [Singularity](http://getsingularity.com/Docs/about/how-it-works.html)
- [Aurora](http://aurora.apache.org/)